# How to tag a friend - similar to facebook (Both imageview and normal text on the same textfield/textview)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tags, uitextfield, uitextview

I am working on a social networking app.
On my Textfield/Textview, I am searching my friend using "@".

Eg:@s will list out all my friends starting in s. When I choose any of these friends, I want them to be tagged (**similar to facebook**).

Thus in my Textfield/Textview, my friend's name will be shown on a UIImageview (**similar to StackOverflow tags which is entered during asking a question**).

**I require both normal text as well as tagged friends on the same textfield.**
Now how can I show this on my Textfield/Textview?

Comment: have you acheive the fucntionality?, if u did, plz suggest me. im also having the requirement. @Ambili B Menon

Answer (score 1):

Please check this third party control [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jstokenfield). It does not include image as you mentioned, but you will get some idea.

As another option, you can create UIScrollView and put whatever controls you want, that is what i will do if i need very customized text entries with images and designs.